# Customizable message processors for Anypoint connector project

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

How to structure message processors? I am developing custom connector using devkit. I have one @Connector class that has around 169 @Processor methods. I want to group @Processor methods in different java class so that i can mange code in future.

If you have any solution regarding this, kindly suggest me best solution.